# painting latex over oil based prep work

Tags: painting, oil-based-paint

Will using a deglosser then Kilz2 before painting be enough? (latex over oil based for indoor trim and doors)

Or is it absolutely necessary to sand and TSP? or oil based Kilz or bonding primer??

The guy at the paint counter said the primer already in my paint will be enough to paint over oil-based paint, but I think he is bonkers. If he's not crazy, please let me know because I'd love to save the work and money!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the liquid sand, deglosser, by the time you rub the de-glosser over all the surfaces it will remove any and all of the gloss, grease, dirt whatever you want, then when you put on a primer are paint , do a little and wait until it dries and see if it will scratch off with your fingernail and if it doesn't your good to go